# Parsing Windows Form variables to the main method for use

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a settings panel for my visualization tool right now that offers granular controls over things displayed on the graph, like choosing the color of text, title text input, etc.

[image]

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
    public HM_SettingsForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void HM_SettingsForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

My question is, in the `main` function, how do I use the outputs of the strings and numbers that are outputted from forms like the title text box?

Say for example, I type "This is a graph" into the Title box, I can use that string in my main method for whatever I need to do with it. Store it into a `String` list, for example.

I declared the following as an instance variable.

`HM_SettingsForm settings = new HM_SettingsForm();`

I was hoping I could parse variables through using a command like this, so I could use it in my application.

`settings.checkBox1.Enabled = ...`

Am I understanding this correctly? I apologize for the newbie question.

Comment: You should get the state via the Checked property instead of Enabled on the checkbox control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your settings class  make public properties as needed

```
public class HM_SettingsForm
    { 


        //just do something like this for all your properties   
       public bool CheckBox1State
        { 
          get{return settings.checkBox1.Checked;}

       }

    }
```

to retrieve results

```
HM_SettingsForm settings = new HM_SettingsForm(); 
bool state= settings.CheckBox1State;
```

Comment: I think it should be `Checked` rather than `Enabled`.

Comment: Hi K.B. I was wondering, so do I change the default code, which is normally `private void comboBox2(object sender, EventArgs e){..}` to `public type comboBox2(..){..}`? Or do I do it underneath? I noticed I get the error: `member is defined more than once` if I declare it again: http://puu.sh/6tj2n/8911836e25.png

Comment: by convention property name should start by a capital letter

Comment: Thanks KB. This is what I ended up using, though I used instance variables instead of local variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Settings class, and use Settings instance to send data in settings form, and get them back:

**Settings class**

```
public class Settings
{
    public string Title {get;set;}
    // ..another props
}
```

**SettingsForm form**

```
private Settings _settings;

public HM_SettingsForm(Settings settings)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _settings = settings;
    titleTextBox.Text = settings.Title;
    // ..another props inialization
}

public void FormClosing(object Sender, FormClosingEventArgs args)
{
    if (!_valid()) {
        args.Cancel = true;
    }
}

public void FormClose(object Sender, EventArgs args)
{
    _settings.Title = titleTextBox.Text;
    // ..another props updating
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks like it's exactly what I need. I will give you a reply once I implement this.

Comment: Also, you should add FormCloseQuery event handler, and validate your settings before close form, and don't close it, if there are some errors.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage This is good way, also check my answer for another way as well

Comment: Hi Alexander. I have a novice question. Notice how my code above says something like `checkBox1_CheckedChanged`? What is the purpose of `_CheckedChanged`? Can I use `checkBox1` simply by calling `checkBox1.Checked`?

Comment: In your code above, change event handlers are not necessary. You should to use FormClosing and FormClose as i wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the built in [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx). It will allow you to store settings to a file and reload them when the app reloads. When loading your app, check the settings and set the font color, title, etc according to the settings.

```
Settings.Default["FontColor"] = "#000FFF"; //Some color
Settings.Default["BackgroundColor"] = "#FFF000"; //Some color
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing it:

1 -  You can create an object, which will represent the data in your pop-up form.

(pseudo-code)

```
class MySettings
{
    bgColor
    textColor
    title
    xAxis
    yAxis
    showTitle
    showText
}
```

Now, add buttons Ok and Cancel. When button Ok is clicked you pass MySettings object and you read out of it to set the properties of the control you trying to modify.

2 -  Here you will create instance of your pop-up form and wire up events of the controls in pop-up to your control, which you trying to modify.

For example, you can create a callback function and pass it up to your popup

```
public delegate void ComboItemCallBackDelegate(string text);

private ComboItemCallBackDelegate _comboCallBack;

public void SetComboCallback(ComboItemCallBackDelegate cb)
{
    _comboCallBack = cb;
}

private void Combo1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e)
{
    _comboCallBack(Combo1.Text);
}
```

This way you will receive changes to your main control as they happen on your popup.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as below:

in your Setting form declare a argumented constructor:

```
  public HM_SettingsForm(String titleText)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
string titleText=this.titleField.text;
test t=new test();
t.main(titleText) // passing titleText to main function of another class or in another form.
}
```

And in the main function call that constructor like below:

```
public class test{ // if main function is in another class or form
Public void main(string titleText)// say main function
{
// do something with the titleText
}
```

}

Hope this helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I may be down-voted for saying this, but I personally would stay away from `Application Settings`. I find them to be much more annoying to use than a simple class used with `XmlSerializer`. Perhaps they were good back in the early days of .NET but I find them to be more annoying than helpful nowadays.

That said, you should definitely create a class that represents all the possible parameters that your `Settings` window will contain, even if they are read-only. So let's go with what you have so far:

```
sealed class GraphSettings
{
  public Color BackgroundColor { get; set; }
  public Color ForegroundColor { get; set; }

  public string Title { get; set; }

  public double OffsetX { get; set; }
  public double OffsetY { get; set; }

  public bool ShowTitle { get; set; }
  public bool ShowText { get; set; }

  public GraphSettings()
  {
    // Set your default values here.
    this.ShowTitle = true;
  }
}
```

Your `Settings` window should contain a `GraphSettings` object that the controls manipulate. Manipulating the controls should reflect changes in the `GraphSettings` property values.

You can then serialize/deserialize (save/load) that object to XML using `XmlSerializer`:

```
static void SaveSettings(GraphSettings settings, string file)
{
  var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GraphSettings));

  using (var stream = File.Create(file))
  {
    serializer.Serialize(stream, settings);

    stream.Flush();
    stream.Close();
  }
}

static GraphSettings LoadSettings(string file)
{
  var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GraphSettings));

  using (var stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
  {
    var settings = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as GraphSettings;
    stream.Close();

    return settings;
  }
}
```

The general flow would be:

1. Load settings file, use defaults if not found/corrupted.
2. Create settings window and set `GraphSettings`.
3. Populate the controls with the values from `GraphSettings`.
4. Update `GraphSettings` with any changes made in the UI.
5. Close the settings window.
6. Save the updated `GraphSettings` from the settings window.
7. Pass the new `GraphSettings` to your `main` function/form.